# can we connect one pardot account with multiple salesforce instances?

Tags: salesforce-id, pardot

As my client acquired by new customer,they looking for possibilities to connect one pardot account with multiple salesfroce instances. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.

You **cannot connect one Pardot to mulitple SF orgs**

However one SF org can be connected to multiple Pardot instances.

You can read more here -> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317388&type=1&mode=1